# Can I resize a UICollectionViewCell height while typing in its subview UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift

A `UITextView` which is configured to automatically resizes its height as I type. This works if I add it to a `UIView`.

I've managed to make it work even in a `UITableVIew`, which means that the `UITableViewCell` resizes its height while typing in the `TextView`.

However this seems not be doable for a `UICollectionView`. I can't figure out how to resize a `UICollectionViewCell` height. I've tried to call

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

while typing in the textview, but it doesn't work. (I've used both notifications or `UITextViewDelegate` methods to trigger the call).

Do you know if it's doable? Please note that the cell should resize the height while typing, and the focus should be kept on the textview so that I can continue to type.

Comment: resizing in manner of width or height or both?

Comment: Try call collectionView's `performBatchUpdates:completion` in the textView's `textViewDidChange` delegate

Comment: @JitendraModi height

Comment: @Tj3n With what arguments and completion closure ?

Comment: Just leave it empty, It probably will have the same effect as tableView's `beginUpdate` which update the frame during typing in textView

Comment: @Tj3n I've just tried and it doesn't work collectionView.performBatchUpdates({})

Comment: you can use this method self.collectionView(self.collectionView, layout: self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath). you can call this methods in textview delegate method so you can get textview's text height So you can change cell height on every linebreak in textview.  I am not saying that this is correct answer but you can try this.

Comment: @JitendraModi So you are suggesting to manually call the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method collectionView(UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath). But this is a method that should never be called manually, right?